# How to prevent battery charging unless dips below 95%? on an Asus U31SD-XH51

Tags: power-management, asus, battery

I have an Asus U31SD-XH51 laptop running latest Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to know if there is a way to prevent the system from charging the battery unless its charged level dips below 95%?

This is a feature I notice from my Windows 7 partition.  According to Asus, while the charge level is at least 95%, the system would not charge in order to prevent deterioration.  However, this is not the case on Ubuntu 12.04 because the system would still charge my battery even at 99%.

Anyone shred some light for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my model, U31SD-XH51, I simply added "acip_backlight=vendor" to grub and update it.  It actually fixing all backlight problem for me.  No longer I need to mess with /etc/rc.local or LMT(laptop-mode-tools).  If anyone got a U-series, please follow the steps below and give it a shot.

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
3. `sudo update-grub`

Best of all, the battery charging concern I am having is fixed as well.  Now, it won't charge unless dips below 95%.